# In Ruby, what is .map method with rand?

Tags: ruby

I am extremely new to Ruby and am unable to understand this piece of code:

```
code = (0...16).map { rand(10).to_s }.join
```

I understand it's generating a random number from 0-9. But what does it have to do with the .map method. What is it trying to perform here? Also, will the code be always unique? Any explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: `(0...6).map { |n| 2*n } #=> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]` *maps* each element of the range `0...6` to twice its value in the array that is returned. Your code, `(0...16).map { |n| rand(10).to_s }` maps each element of a range to a random number between `0` and `9` converted to a string. The block variable `n` is not used in that calculation so the block can be written without reference to it (`{ rand(10).to_s }`).

Comment: _"I am extremely new to Ruby"_ – Ruby comes with a command line tool called [`irb`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html). It allows you to interactively execute Ruby expressions like your code above.

Comment: _"will the code be always unique"_ – are you asking if 16 random digits will be unique? :-)

Comment: @AgniswarBakshi : The code would be much more understandable if written as `17.times.map { rand(10).to_s }.join` or as `Array.new(17) { rand(10).to_s }.join` or `"%017d" % rand(10**17-1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
code = (0...16).map { rand(10).to_s }.join
```

Is used to generate the random string which contains (0 to 9) of length 16. `.map` will return an array with length of number of times it is iterating (here 16 times). `.join` is used to join all this `16` elements & return a string

```
2.2.4 :004 > code = (0...16).map {rand(10).to_s}
 => ["9", "2", "7", "4", "8", "2", "2", "9", "0", "8", "5", "1", "3", "2", "7", "8"] 
2.2.4 :005 > code = (0...16).map {rand(10).to_s}.join
 => "8371524929956722" 
2.2.4 :006 > code = (0...16).map {rand(10).to_s}.join
 => "4111661481960314" 
2.2.4 :007 >
```

you can use following as well to generate the same result

```
code = rand(10 ** 16).to_s
 => "7066995392533658"
2.2.4 :011 > code = rand(10 ** 16).to_s
 => "9149902415985481"
```

Comment: Can also be done with `16.times.map { rand(10).to_s }.join`

Comment: _"you can use following as well to generate the same result"_ – not quite, you have to pad the strings with zeros for numbers with less than 16 digits, e.g. `'%016d' % rand(10 ** 16)`

Comment: Alternatively: `Array.new(16) { rand(10) }.join`

Answer (score 2):

```
code = (0...16).map { rand(10).to_s }.join
```

The above code is generating random numbers from 0 to 9 16 times and returning the string of the generated random numbers.

To clearly understand, let's break down the individual code components.

```
(0...16)
```

This creates a range of integers from 0 to 15.

```
(0...16).map { code-block }
```

This executes the code-block for each of the elements in the range and returns the output. The result of this operation is a new array which contains output computed for each element.

```
rand(10)
```

This generates random integer, greater than or equal to 0 but less than 10.

```
rand(10).to_s
```

This converts the generated integer to string.

```
(0...16).map { rand(10).to_s }.join
```

This finally joins each of the string we obtained after random number generation.

Hope this helps you understand it better.

Comment: Thanks a lot..that was great!

Comment: _"executes the code-block for each of the elements"_ – that's what `each` would do. `map` does much more.

Answer (score 0):

The `(0...16).map { ... }` just executes the block (the stuff in the curly braces) sixteen times and stores the sixteen results of executing the block in an array. If you open IRB and type in `(0...16).map { rand(10).to_s }`, you will see that you get an array of strings like this:

```
["9", "5", "3", "6", "0", "9", "5", "0", "6", "5", "2", "5", "7", "5", "5", "3"]
```

You should read the documentation for the `map` and `join` methods to see how they work:

- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map
- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join